# How to multiply rows with corresponding columns in Python (cuPy/Numpy)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, cupy

I need to multiply each row with a column at the corresponding row-index. Consider the graphics below in which I have a `3 x 3` matrix. The required operation is to multiply the  `row[0]` of matrix with `col[0]` of `transposed_matrix`, `row[1]` of matrix with `col[1]` of `transposed_matrix`,  and so on.

[image]

**Question:** How can achieve it in **cupPy/Numpy** Python in a smart way (i.e. without using for-loops)?

Comment: Is the output a single row? or you want all?

Comment: @mozway: yes, single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want:

```
out = (A**2).sum(axis=1)
```

Example:

```
# input
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

# output
array([ 14,  77, 194])
```

Since you want the equivalent of `sum(1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3)` for each row.

If A and B are different matrices, then use:

```
out = (A*B.T).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: dot product would produce a 3 x 3 matrix. I need only a row vector.

Comment: @skm Yes, I initially thought your example want incomplete. See update

Comment: Thanks, in this case, the square would work. But is there a generic way, in case the two matrices are different.

Comment: @skm yes of course, see update

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 3X3 array:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
             [4, 5, 6],
             [7, 8, 9]])
```

you can do:

```
A@A.T
```

but, it will produce 3X3 output

```
array([[ 14,  32,  50],
       [ 32,  77, 122],
       [ 50, 122, 194]])
```

so, if you want your desired output:

---

```
np.diag(A@A.T)

#array([ 14,  77, 194])
```

---

When the matrices are different:

```
B = np.array([
    [4,3,2],
    [6,9,7],
    [8,4,3]
])

np.diag(A@B.T)

#output
array([ 16, 111, 115])
```

Comment: But that's inefficient, you waste most of the computing

Comment: You can skip the diagonal with `np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A,B)` or  `np.squeeze(A[:,None,:]@B[:,:,None])`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? It uses the first list to multiply its rows with the columns of the second one.

It transposes the second list so that we can multiply both arrays.

```
import numpy as np

first = [
    [2,3,5],
    [4,6,7],
    [9,7,5]
]
second = [
    [4,3,2],
    [6,9,7],
    [8,4,3]
]

first = np.array(first)
second = np.array(second)

print(first* second.T)
```

For the row-vector you can use a list comprehension like so:

```
print([sum(row) for row in (first * second.T)])
```

Comment: wrong, as I mentioned above, the output should be a row-vector

Comment: do you mean one long vector with all results?